# How to find the end of a memory mapped file in Windows platform without previously knowing the size of the file?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, virtual-memory, file-mapping

I have mapped a file of unknown size (around 4-6 GiB) in Windows platform and got a pointer to the start of the file data returned from the MapFileView function. But how can I know that I have reached the end of the file when I access the data using the pointer sequentially?

Here is the code I have so far written and it successfully maps the file and returns the pointer:

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <inttypes.h>

    int main()
    {
      HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("Test.bin",
                                 GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                 0,
                                 NULL,
                                 OPEN_EXISTING,
                                 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                 NULL);
      if (!hFile)
      {
        printf("Could not create file (%lu).\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1) ;
      }

      HANDLE hMapFile = CreateFileMappingA(hFile,
                                           NULL,
                                           PAGE_READWRITE,
                                           0,
                                           0,
                                           NULL);
      if (!hMapFile)
      {
        printf("Could not create file mapping object (%lu).\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        exit(1);
      }

      int32_t* pBuf = (int32_t*) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,
                                               FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
                                               0,
                                               0,
                                               0);
      if (!pBuf)
      {
        printf("Could not map file (%lu).\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
        exit(1);
      };

      UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);
      CloseHandle(hFile);
      CloseHandle(hMapFile);

      exit(0);
    }
```

So I wanted to read equal sized different parts of the file simultaneously in multiple threads. I believe mapped file is the right choice for this purpose. Advice about any other faster and possible approaches is highly appreciated.

I have researched some similar questions in the forum and I suppose this is the closest topic I could find: 
[Read all contents of memory mapped file or Memory Mapped View Accessor without knowing the size of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953393/read-all-contents-of-memory-mapped-file-or-memory-mapped-view-accessor-without-k)
But this answer is using C# and is not written using the WinAPI, therefore, I couldn't understand their process.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Call `GetFileSizeEx` to get the size of a file. Reading different parts of the file simultaneously is like to be slower than reading sequentially.

Comment: Why not using [`GetFileSizeEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex) function to get the file size ? You could also use the [`VirtualQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualquery) function to get the size of the mapping view. I assume that if the file is too big MapViewOfFile will fail. Have you checked that you could map the full file ?

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan. But is there any way to know the end without knowing the size? Moreover, could you please help me understand why simultaneous reading is like to be slower even with memory mapped files?

Comment: @chmike Thanks for the response. I won't be mapping the whole file in a single view, rather I plan to create views of 500 MiB  for each thread, which I guess should be okay. Do I understand it right? 
I could certainly use the file size, you are right. But I was curious if it could be done without knowing the size. Does files have an ending marker that indicates where it ends?

Comment: How do you think the filesystem knows that the file pointer has reached the end of the file? It knows that because it knows the size. Certainly if it's a spinning disk then reading sequentially is faster. I'm not sure about SSDs, but I'm not sure that they necessarily have bus architecture that supports parallel access, or that the system can take advantage. Let's turn this around, why do you think parallel access would be faster?

Comment: @RohanSaha 500MiB would indeed be ok. Concurrent access to the file won’t be faster than serial access if the file is not yet in memory because the access to the disk is sequential. But once in memory cache, concurrent access will be faster.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks again. Well, I thought that if the file is already cached in the memory, then I don't have to create a separate buffer for each thread to receive the read data from the file. I wanted parallel access to send parts of the file simultaneously through different ports over the LAN network.

Comment: @chmike is there any function to force the memory caching from the disk? I know `FlushViewOfFile` forces disk write from the mapped view of file.

Comment: @chmike you need to read the file to load it in memory. If you have an SSD disk, concurrent access may be faster. It depends what you do with the data. If you do a complex operation requiring processing time, you could see a performance benefit with a parallel code since one thread might load a part of the file while the other is processing the data. If processing is very fast, the bottleneck will be loading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `GetFileSizeEx` to get the size of a file, and use this in combination with the base address and the current read address to determine where the end address is.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess how fread/fgetc knows that it has reached the end of file is somewhat similar to this and then returns EOF (a define macro) for user convenience. Is that so?

Comment: @roh: No, it's not similar. `fread`/`fgetc` do not use file mapping objects.

Comment: @IInspectable Yea I know that. Sorry, I meant without the file mapping objects. What I meant is it gets the file size, reads through the file and compares the size of the read data. Something similar of this sort maybe.

Comment: @roh: `fread`/`fgetc` probably just call into [ReadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile), and have that API report EOF. However that is implemented is not known to me.