# Read memory mapped file or knowing its size to read it correctely

Tags: c#, .net, ipc, memory-mapped-files

In this question,

[Read all contents of memory mapped file or Memory Mapped View Accessor without knowing the size of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953393/read-all-contents-of-memory-mapped-file-or-memory-mapped-view-accessor-without-k)

there is a problem, the `(int)stream.Length` is not giving me the correct length, it rather gives the size of the internal buffer used! I need to refresh this question because it is very pressing.

The main question was:

> I need something similar to ReadToEnd or ReadAllBytes to read all of
>   the contents of the MemoryMappedFile using the MappedViewAccessor if I
>   don't know the size of it, how can I do it?
>
> I have searched for it, I have seen this question, but it is not the
>   thing I am looking for:
>
> How can I quickly read bytes from a memory mapped file in .NET?

The old answer was:

pub

```
public static ReadMMFAllBytes(string fileName)
{
    using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(fileName))
    {
        using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
        {
            using (BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                return binReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this question:

[Memory Mapped File Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597541/memory-mapped-file-length?rq=1)

There is no exact answer of the exact question! the question is about something else than the title.

Comment: Did this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8613300/2258  Or Jon Skeet's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/221941/2258

Comment: Didn't work, it gives me 4096 bytes even if the file is empty:(

Comment: Just write the stream length as well, at the beginning of the view.

Comment: I am failing to see a question here. Can you edit the question make it clear about exactly what you're asking?

Comment: Simply, I need to read the memory mapped file without a previous information about it's size, If I tried to read it as I read any other stream, it will be with a wrong size, it's size will be rounded to X4096 number (Or to the closest system page size).

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to send over a fixed-length header of sorts first, rather than just streaming raw bytes.  This way the first blob you read is a consistent length and it gives you the info you need to read the variable-length remainder.

In the simplest case, your record could be as simple as having a length field written first, followed by the payload (your bytes).  Depending on your needs, you can add data to the header like record type, version, etc.